# Plotting with time axis (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I ran into a problem again thats causing me headache for several hours already...and I'm pretty sure it's just a minor thing.

I got a long datafile and created a list with the header names and their types:

```
col_headers = [('TIMESTAMP','|S21'),('XXX_1','<i8'),('YYY_2','<i8')
```

After that I created a dictionary variable that holds the options and finally imported it with

```
bladata = scipy.genfromtxt(datafile, **kwargs)
```

For extracting time information I used

```
import datetime as dt
for i in range (0,len(bladata['TIMESTAMP']),1):
    datestring = bladata['TIMESTAMP'][i]
    #create a datetime object holding dates and times
    d = dt.datetime.strptime(datestring, '"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"')
```

And finally I assigned the data to a variable by using

```
XXX = bladata['XXX_1']
YYY = bladata['YYY_2']
```

(btw when the header name in my datafile is not XXX_1 but XXX(1) instead, I receive the error message "field named XXX(1) not found" - how can I solve this problem as well?)

Now when it comes to plotting, I receive the error message

```
x and y must have same first dimension
```

when using the following code

```
pylab.plot(dt, XXX)
pylab.plot(dt, YYY)
pylab.xlim(d.datetime(2014, 01, 10), d.datetime(2014, 06, 10))
```

I googled that error message and found a solution that suggested converting a list into a numpy array...but where and which one? I'm pretty sure that isn't a big problem at all, but I couldn't figure it out for several hours...so I'm happy for any usefull reply.

€dit: for clarification...XXX and YYY are 2 different measurements that I want to visualize in 1 plot versus its corresponding date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `pylab.plot(dt, XXX)` you're trying to plot the imported `datetime` module itself against a list of values, which is not what you want.

Instead you want something like `pylab.plot(times, XXX)` where `times` should be a list containing the `datetime` objects corresponding to the list `XXX`.

The error message you are getting is pointing out the 2 arguments you pass to the `plot` function should be lists of the same length.

See [Plotting time in Python with Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574088/plotting-time-in-python-with-matplotlib) for further information including formatting the x-axis labels.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion...XXX and YYY are 2 different type of data that I want to visualize in the same plot but with the same temporal range (from TIMESTAMP)! So I want to plot XXX and YYY versus its corresponding date.

Comment: Edited to expand on my explanation and to correct my answer with your clarification. Let me know if you need any more explanation.

Comment: Oh god...all I needed was that tiny `date2num` function...took me the whole day to figure that out. Now everything works, thank you!